# How to show the translation of a web page in Google?

Tags: google-search

I used to find "translation" click-able for translation of language of each web page found by Google but I don't have it anymore.

How to show the translation of a web page in Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Translation Browser Buttons](http://translate.google.com/translate_buttons) is an official collection of bookmarklets usable in any browser.

To use, simply drag the link to your link bar for the language you are going to want to translate ***TO***. (In my case, that'd be English.)

Then, when you find a web page you want to translate, simply click the link in your link bar. If you only want to translate a portion, select the text to translate then click the link.

Answer (score 2):

In Google Chrome, go to the wrench menu, select "Preferences..." and then, "Under the Hood".
Make sure the option "Offer to translate pages that aren't in the language I read" is checked (see picture).

To set your default reading languages, click that big "Languages and Spell-checker settings..." button.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I sometimes use Google Chrome, but my main browser is Firefox.

Comment: I wonder how to do that in Firefox?